# GUI apps on WSL/Debian

Tags: debian, gui, wsl2, wayland

So we are supposed to be able to [run Linux GUI apps on the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

However, as per [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Microsoft/Windows/SubsystemForLinux):

> To activate the new GUI application support you have to update your WSL2 environment to Debian bookworm or later.

So the question is, ***how***?  As I mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1722935/wsl-debian-is-still-on-oldoldstable-any-way-to-get-latest), Debian on WSL is still on oldoldstable.

From oldoldstable to bookworm is four major releases.

Moreover, WSL uses its own MS built kernels, we cannot simply do the distro upgrade I suppose.

Comment: You actually should just be able to initiate the appropriate commands.  [I found no shortage of articles, on how to manually upgrade an Ubuntu 18.04 WSL instance to 20.04](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-upgrade-wsl-2-or-1-ubuntu-20-04-to-22-04-lts/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debian wiki just seems wrong on that topic.  WSLg support is not dependent on the Debian distribution.  You could run a minimal distribution with an `xterm` from 10 years ago, and I'm fairly confident it would still launch.

At the least, I can tell you that I just installed Debian Stretch as part of answering [your other question](https://superuser.com/q/1722935/1210833), did a normal `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, then installed and ran `xterm` without any issue.

For something more complex, I installed Gimp (still under Stretch) and it also ran without issue (well, other than the normal annoyance of the [font error](https://superuser.com/q/1722959/1210833) that I just ignore for the most part).

It is, of course, better to use a more recent distro for *other* reasons, but WSLg will handle Stretch (and likely any distro) for normal GUI app usage.

> Moreover, WSL uses its own MS built kernels, we cannot simply do the distro upgrade I suppose.

Sure -- There's typically no problem with updating a distro under WSL when you need to.  The kernel in the distro isn't used, but that doesn't impact most user-level configuration.  It pretty much works the same as if you were running Debian in a container, because you are.  The Debian packages in the container can be upgraded regardless of the host kernel.

Not saying that you might not run into normal upgrade pains/incompatibilities/etc.  But the WSL2 kernel won't prevent it.