# xterm: cannot load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm getting the following error from Ubuntu-22.04 within WSL

`xterm: cannot load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"`

Note again it is from Ubuntu-22.04 *within WSL*, as I didn't got it when working with *normal* Ubuntu 22.04.

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

$ apt-cache policy xbitmaps
xbitmaps:
  Installed: 1.1.1-2.1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.1.1-2.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1-2.1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Side-note:  This error should no longer occur on recent WSL releases.  The WSLg implementation now bind-mounts your distribution into WSLg so that it can use the installed fonts directly.*

*For older systems, or just to understand the "how-to" ...*

To set the font when starting `xterm`, first get a list of your installed fonts with:

```
fc-list
```

On Ubuntu on WSL, it looks like "DejaVuSansMono" is installed by default, and it's a nice fixed-width terminal-type font.

You can try it out by launching xterm and specifying the font face (and likely size) with:

```
xterm -fs 14 -fa DejaVuSansMono
```

If that font works for you, you can make it permanent by creating a `~/.Xresources` with:

```
xterm*faceName: DejaVuSansMono
xterm*faceSize: 14
```

And then merge it into your X resources database with:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Side note:  I spent a while trying to determine exactly why this error doesn't appear on a standard Ubuntu distribution, and the only thing I can think is that something in the Desktop manager installation or user-configuration handles the resources there.  For instance, when running `xterm` under xfce4 under Ubuntu, the message doesn't appear.

Comment: Mostly copied from another answer I gave here.  I can't use the other question as a duplicate, since my answer there never received any upvotes, so I'll add it here.

Comment: thanks a lot NotTheDr01ds. This is exactly the information that I was trying to find out myself. Note the problem is really specific to WSL, as you have kind of spotted -- It turns out that the above problem in OP only happens when I use WSL2's built-in xserver [wslg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg). If I set my DISPLAY to my own normal xserver, then there won't be such problem. But still, your answer is exactly the information that I was looking for. thanks.

Comment: It's 2024, I'm using WSL version 2.0.9.0 with WSLg 1.0.59 and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: @crockeea Thanks for the heads-up.  And bummer :-/